# ROBLOX GUI/Leaderboard stats

Tags: roblox

Im trying to get data to show from a PlayersGui onto the leaderboard but nothing seems to work, i have asked on the forums but cant seem to get the help i need.

Here is my current script, can someone tell me what is wrong/what i am missing.
(it doesnt show up the leaderboard, just my name)

```
local Settings = require(script.Parent.Settings)
script.Parent = game.ServerScriptService
--Players = game.Players.LocalPlayer
--pg=Players.Player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
--diamonds=pg:WaitForChild("Ores").Frame.diamonds.Number.Bar
stands = {}
CTF_mode = false

function onHumanoidDied(humanoid, player)
local stats = player:findFirstChild("leaderstats")
if stats ~= nil then
    local deaths = stats:findFirstChild(Settings.LeaderboardSettings.DeathsName)
    if deaths then
        deaths.Value = deaths.Value + 1
    end
    -- do short dance to try and find the killer
    if Settings.LeaderboardSettings.KOs then
        local killer = getKillerOfHumanoidIfStillInGame(humanoid)
        handleKillCount(humanoid, player)
    end
end
end

function onPlayerRespawn(property, player)
-- need to connect to new humanoid

if property == "Character" and player.Character ~= nil then
    local humanoid = player.Character.Humanoid
    local p = player
    local h = humanoid
    if Settings.LeaderboardSettings.WOs then
        humanoid.Died:connect(function() onHumanoidDied(h, p) end )
    end
end
end

function getKillerOfHumanoidIfStillInGame(humanoid)
-- returns the player object that killed this humanoid
-- returns nil if the killer is no longer in the game

-- check for kill tag on humanoid - may be more than one - todo: deal with this
local tag = humanoid:findFirstChild("creator")

-- find player with name on tag
if tag ~= nil then

    local killer = tag.Value
    if killer.Parent ~= nil then -- killer still in game
        return killer
    end
end

return nil
end

function handleKillCount(humanoid, player)
local killer = getKillerOfHumanoidIfStillInGame(humanoid)
if killer ~= nil then
    local stats = killer:findFirstChild("leaderstats")
    if stats ~= nil then
        local kills = stats:findFirstChild(Settings.LeaderboardSettings.KillsNames)
        if kills then
            if killer ~= player then
                kills.Value = kills.Value + 1   
            else
                kills.Value = kills.Value - 1
            end
        else
            return
        end
    end
end
end


-----------------------------------------------



function findAllFlagStands(root)
local c = root:children()
for i=1,#c do
    if (c[i].className == "Model" or c[i].className == "Part") then
        findAllFlagStands(c[i])
    end
    if (c[i].className == "FlagStand") then
        table.insert(stands, c[i])
    end
end
end

function hookUpListeners()
for i=1,#stands do
    stands[i].FlagCaptured:connect(onCaptureScored)
end
end

function onPlayerEntered(newPlayer)

if CTF_mode == true then

    local stats = Instance.new("IntValue")
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local captures = Instance.new("IntValue")
    captures.Name = "Captures"
    captures.Value = 0


    captures.Parent = stats

    -- VERY UGLY HACK
    -- Will this leak threads?
    -- Is the problem even what I think it is (player arrived before character)?
    while true do
        if newPlayer.Character ~= nil then break end
        wait(5)
    end

    stats.Parent = newPlayer

else

    local stats = Instance.new("IntValue")
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    local kills = false
    if Settings.LeaderboardSettings.KOs then
        kills = Instance.new("IntValue")
        kills.Name = Settings.LeaderboardSettings.KillsName
        kills.Value = 0
    end
    local deaths = false
    if Settings.LeaderboardSettings.WOs then
        deaths = Instance.new("IntValue")
        deaths.Name = Settings.LeaderboardSettings.DeathsName
        deaths.Value = 0
    end

    local cash = false
    if Settings.LeaderboardSettings.ShowCurrency then
        cash = Instance.new("StringValue")
        cash.Name = Settings.CurrencyName
        cash.Value = 0
    end

    local PlayerStats = game.ServerStorage.PlayerMoney:FindFirstChild(newPlayer.Name)
    if PlayerStats ~= nil then
        if cash then
            local Short = Settings.LeaderboardSettings.ShowShortCurrency
            PlayerStats.Changed:connect(function()
                if (Short) then
                    cash.Value = Settings:ConvertShort(PlayerStats.Value)
                else
                    cash.Value = Settings:ConvertComma(PlayerStats.Value)
                end
            end)
        end
    end
    if kills then
    kills.Parent = stats
    end
    if deaths then
    deaths.Parent = stats
    end
    if cash then
    cash.Parent = stats
    end

    -- VERY UGLY HACK
    -- Will this leak threads?
    -- Is the problem even what I think it is (player arrived before character)?
    while true do
        if newPlayer.Character ~= nil then break end
        wait(5)
    end

    local humanoid = newPlayer.Character.Humanoid

    humanoid.Died:connect(function() onHumanoidDied(humanoid, newPlayer) end )

    -- start to listen for new humanoid
    newPlayer.Changed:connect(function(property) onPlayerRespawn(property, newPlayer) end )


    stats.Parent = newPlayer

end

end


function onCaptureScored(player)

    local ls = player:findFirstChild("leaderstats")
    if ls == nil then return end
    local caps = ls:findFirstChild("Captures")
    if caps == nil then return end
    caps.Value = caps.Value + 1

end


findAllFlagStands(game.Workspace)
hookUpListeners()
if (#stands > 0) then CTF_mode = true end
game.Players.ChildAdded:connect(onPlayerEntered)
```

Comment: Have you tried making a minimal example?  That is way too much code to test.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this inside the function "handleKillCount":

```
function handleKillCount(humanoid, player)
local findkiller = getKillerOfHumanoidIfStillInGame(humanoid)
local killer = game.Players[findKiller.Value]

if killer ~= nil then
    local stats = killer:findFirstChild("leaderstats")
    if stats ~= nil then
        local kills = stats:findFirstChild(Settings.LeaderboardSettings.KillsNames)
        if kills then
            if killer ~= player then
                kills.Value = kills.Value + 1   
            else
                kills.Value = kills.Value - 1
            end
        else
            return
        end
    end
end
end
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help! I'd appreciate it if you marked the answer as correct, too. :)